# Using events in AngularJS with data attribute to avoid direct dependency

Tags: javascript, angularjs

I’m using the `$rootScope` in a service and broadcast several events via `$rootScope.$broadcast(eventName)`. The service also provide several `getXYZ()` methods to retrieve service data in place.

Some broadcasted events are de-facto notifications of XYZ service data changed. A controller in the root scope can catch the event via `$scope.$on(eventName,handler(){…})`, and call the service `getXYZ()` method(s) in the handler. In that case, the controller must necessarily declare the service and dependent on it.

I’ve found practical passing XYZ data to broadcasted event via 2nd parameter in `$rootScope.$broadcast(eventName,data)`, and then use the data directly in a controller event handler `$scope.$on(eventName, handler(e,data){…})`, thus it’s not necessary to declare the service dependency in the controller.

Is the solution above acceptable in AngularJS? Or there are some limits I have to consider when broadcasting data on the root scope?

Comment: It is common practice to include parameters with events. To do otherwise is a bit strange.

Comment: I do not think there is a benefit of hiding dependencies anyway. Since you need that `xyz` Data, you are depending on the `xyz` Service. Also, i do not think that raising an event on the rootScope for every data change is considered as good practice.